# Multi-Page form with dynamic number of pages JSF

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, wizard

I need to make multi page form/wizard for my javaEE/JSF web application. On the first page user inputs number of his family members, than after clicking next, there should be as many steps generated as saved members, so one page per member.The schema of this family member pages is the same. So how to implement wizard or form without hard-coded number of steps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too much a homework question

Comment: Hey, I need to oppose here, I don't ask for ready to go example, but rather a suggestion on technology/framework etc.I simply don't know how to bite this. Each problem on stack can be seen "homework-like" if you insist.

Comment: I can understand that you look at it this way, but 'Suggestions on technology framework are off-topic... See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, point 4. (your other one is point 3). A valid answer would be: Use java, cdi, jsf, jpa2, (or rather Java-ee) and in addition PrimeFaces and OmniFaces. But I doubt this is helpful. Hence your question is a 'homework' one (no not all on stack are...).

Comment: E.g. Can you get a list populated on the first 'page'? Can you then show a new (partial) page with the first member? Can you add a next/prev button? Can you keep track of which member you are editing? All very basic things you can and should try... If you have actual concrete coding problems, we are more than happy to help out

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway, I will try better next time.